# How do I find out about the technical details of an LED if I don't have the fact sheet?

Tags: led

I have bought a bunch of LEDs from the rummage table of my local electronics store. Now, I don't have a fact sheet, neither I do know the vendor and / or the article number.

How do I find out about the desired voltage and current of the LEDs (without doing it trial-and-error)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer: you can't. But you can do some smart non destructive trial and error.

First of all you need to at least know what current/voltage you are expecting: are they power leds, are they small 3mm leds, are they smd or not, what color are they? Try to find a datasheet of a led you think is similar.

Let's assume that you find a somewhat related datasheet so you have the forward current and voltage. You will need a bench psu for this, or a power adapter and a variable resistor, and in both cases a multimeter. You start by building a circuit that will let some 1/10 of the current from the datasheet at the same forward voltage, you then slowly increase the current until you are satisfied. You can possibly burn some leds but you'll probably get away with it.

Shorter answer: no datasheet, no buying.

Answer (score 3):

A lot of common LEDs have very similar specs. For example, if I picked up a jellybean red LED, my first guess at its specs would be \$V_F = 2.0 V\$, \$I_F = 20mA\$. If you're just using these as a hobbyist, numbers like those should be close enough to make them light up on a breadboard. You probably don't need to get close to the rated current anyways - for me, \$1\$ or \$2 mA\$ is enough to tell that the light is on.

See if you can find some generic LED datasheets for the colors of LED that you have, and use those sheets as a baseline.

Answer (score 2):

Measure the forward voltage and observe the color (preferably comparing to known wavelength LEDs) in order to find the chip type. You can make some guesses by looking at them- if they're of cheap construction and look like overruns from a toy maker, they're probably not a chip comparable to the best Avago or Cree ones.

Measure the Vf vs. I curve- easily done with a bench power supply and inexpensive handheld multimeter. Use something like a 499 ohm 1% resistor and gradually increase the voltage, measuring the voltage across the LED and the resistor to give Vf and If.

Observe the **size of the die** and **package** and compare with datasheets you can find online (using all the before-mentioned information) to get an idea of the maximum ratings. Take off some factor (25% 30% or whatever) for the possibility the unknown ones may be made using inferior materials or design. You can easily check if the leadframe is steel or copper with a magnet.

Test the LEDs and discard ones that seem unusually dim compared to others- they're probably damaged.

Or just buy known good ones like most of us...

Answer (score -1):

Roden.. 
If the LEDs are 1/4watts rated then the voltage have to apply is 2V.
You can use a resistor to protect the LED.
To find out the current you need to use the formula V=IR, P=VI.
Here v is voltage across LED.
I is current.
P is power.
R is resistance.